# MediaElement's SetSource using a custom stream inheriting from IsolatedStorageFileStream

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, stream, mediaelement

I have a class called XorIsoStoreFileStream inheriting from IsolatedStorageFileStream, and the point is that using this class, stuff is written with an XOR "encryption" and it can also be read using this class when it XORs it back. For example:

```
public override int Read( byte[] buffer, int offset, int count )
{
    int startbyte = (int)base.Position;
    int readlength = base.Read( buffer, offset, count );
    xor( startbyte, buffer );

    return readlength;
}
```

This seems to be working okay everywhere else in the program. Now I need to play an mp3 file from there, and because of the overridden Read and ReadByte, it should work just as if I'd given SetSource an IsolatedStorageFileStream. It will not take my Xor class though. When I hit play, it hits a NotSupportedException at the SetSource line saying, "Stream must be of type IsolatedStorageFileStream".

```
using( var appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication() )
{
    if( appStorage.FileExists( path ) )
    {
        using( var stream = new XorIsoStoreFileStream( path, FileMode.Open, appStorage ) )
        {
            App.MainAudioPlayer.SetSource( stream );  // how to put Xor stream here?
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something else I can override, like SetSource itself? Doesn't seem like that'd help.
Do I have to implement MediaStreamSource? That seems like huge overkill, reinventing the wheel, etc.
Or is this just not going to work? Will I have to save decrypted parts of the file to a temporary place and SetSource to a normal IsolatedStorageFileStream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `MediaStreamSource`, but that will be quite time-consuming. It would be much easier in your case to process an instance of `IsolatedStorageFileStream` right before playback and passing it to the `MediaElement` instead of having overrides and passing a custom class.

You will have problems passing custom classes, since you need to use a native `IsolatedStorageFileStream` to pass it through `SetSource`, as it is stated [in the official doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190669%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

> Passing a generic stream to SetSource(System.IO.Stream) is not
>   supported in Silverlight for Windows Phone. However, the
>   IsolatedStorageFileStream class, which derives from Stream, is
>   suppoted on Silverlight for Windows Phone.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Dennis! Not having the full readable file on the disk is a requirement, though... how can I avoid that if I pass in a working `IsolatedStorageFileStream`? I might have to suck it up and use `MediaStreamSource`, but I was really hoping there was some other trick or possible workaround I wasn't seeing.

Comment: But you are already loading the file from the local storage, am I right (considering your example above)? So it's already stored somewhere.

Comment: Yes, but the Xor class is also saving the file (from the internet) to isolated storage, so it's all xor'd up and MediaElement can't play it as is when it using a normal stream that doesn't decipher it.

Comment: Look at the updated answer. Your optimal choice would be `MediaStreamSource` that will be used through the same `SetSource`.

Comment: Bummer. I guess that's what I'll do. There's an mp3 implementation of it here already https://github.com/loarabia/ManagedMediaHelpers but it plays garbled audio for me (using a regular IsolatedStorageFileStream with no xoring happening anywhere). Things take effort, what's new.

Comment: Take a look at this sample here: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/10/01/mediastreamsource-sample-with-source-code.aspx

Comment: at http://clipflair.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Client/Media/Audio/ManagedMediaHelpers/Mp3MediaStreamSource.SL4/Mp3MediaStreamSource.cs I've done some fix to enable rewind back to source which wasn't supported for the Mp3MediaStreamSource of ManagedMediaHelpers